# JSF Validation Server Side vs Custom Validators

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I've noticed that if I use a custom validator and also have validation in an actionListener or action that the custom validator gets executed first and the actionListener/action method never gets executed if there is a failure in the custom validator.  Is there any way to run all validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. You should also not do the validation in action(listener) methods. You should use a *real* `Validator` to do validation.

True, the way how JSF default validation works is sometimes frustrating, but there are certainly ways to achieve the particular functional requirement using a *real* `Validator`. Feel free to ask a new question about that.